Is it possible to assign type of sibling property to another property in nested Object?
I want to create function, let's call it test, that will take nested object with dynamic keys in first level and offer you type of method automatically so I don't have to manually type it, however it will still takes generic types of another methods and properties passed, example for explanation below.
type NestedProperties = {
property: () => any,
  anotherProperty: () => any,
  key: (...args: any) => string[],
  method: (data: ReturnType<Test['property']>) => any,
}

Example usage:

function test<T extends Record<string, NestedProperties>>(obj: T){}

function key({ productId }: { productId: number }) {
  return [ 'list', { productId } ]
}

test({
  list: {
    property: () => 'string',
    anotherProperty: () => 1, // will not result as () => any.
    key, // this will also not result as (...args: any) => string[]
    method: (data) /* and this will automatically infer type of returntype of list.property*/ {
       ...do something
    }
  }
});


Does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Kinda. however I still need to get typed another properties as generic that will be passed, I'm passing 5 functions, that needs to persist their own types. @jcalz

Without a [mre] it's hard to tell what you're looking for. Where do you need these persisted? Could you please [edit] to show what "5 functions" looks like? Or at least more than one?

@jcalz I Updated example with one function, it just needs to be generic.

Unfortunately I have no idea what  "this will also not result as (...args: any) => string[]" is supposed to mean. It doesn't return a string[] but you've defined the key prop of NestedProperties to return a string[] so of course there's an error. What are you hoping for and where? With this example I'd just change string to unknown, and if that doesn't suffice you really need to give a [mre] that makes it very clear what the desired behavior is. Also note that method: (data) {} is syntactically invalid so I have to fix that every time you change stuff.

I suspect that if you need much more generic inference at the same time you need contextual inference, you're going to hit ms/TS#53018. And you might either have to give up on contextual typing for callbacks, or on pushing everything in one big object, and you might switch to builders or helper functions. But until I see a [mre] as I asked in my previous comment that motivates extra generics, it's hard to say.

Yep, I hit the issue you posted. I'll take different approach, thank you. @jcalz

So what should we do here? Which version of the question should we answer, and do my above comments constitute an acceptable answer if I write them up?

You can use TypeScript's utility types such as ReturnType and conditional types. Here's how you can define the test function to automatically infer the type of data parameter in the method property based on the return type of property:
type NestedProperties<T> = {
    property: () => T;
    anotherProperty: () => any;
    method: (data: ReturnType<NestedProperties<T>['property']>) => any;
};

function test<T extends Record<string, NestedProperties<any>>>(obj: T) {}

// Example usage
test({
    list: {
        property: () => 'string',
        anotherProperty: () => undefined,
        method: (data) => {
            // data will be inferred as 'string'
            // Do something with data
        },
    },
});

Hopefully it will help, wish you best of luck! :)

Hi, I've tried this approach, you will get (data) as type any.
